# Seemingly random disappearance of cookie predominantly in Edge

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, microsoft-edge, setcookie, httpcookie

## Environment

- I can reliably reproduce in Edge 18
- Edge 44.17763.1.0

I have also observed the same failure but less frequently in other browsers. We use bugsnag to track these type of errors and see the browser breakdown as:

[image]

## Behaviour

Every now and then a single authentication cookie is dropped from a XHR request to a backend server resulting in a HTTP 403. Another XHR request to the same origin server a few milliseconds before and after do send the cookie and get an OK response.

## Particulars

- In total there are 18 cookies being sent on the successful requests. 17 on the broken one.
- The cookie is not near expiry time (there are 2 days left). The cookie was first set on a request which completed several seconds before the new XHR request was initiated and requests prior to this one do have the cookie present.
- The cookie has no explicit path or domain attribute set
- The cookie is marked as `secure` and `httpOnly`.
- The cookie is quite long, the cookie name is 47 ASCII chars.
- Cookie values are 64 hex chars.
- All requests are HTTP GETS.
- A successful request request looks like: `https://api.mysite.com/a/b/c/d`
- The unsuccessful one looks like: `https://api.mysite.com/a/b/c`
- Refreshing the page yields the same result.

Although the cookie names and values are quite long and 18 cookies feels like quite a few, I'm not aware of a specific limit I breached from articles like this: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2008/05/17/browser-cookie-restrictions/

The other strange thing is that the requests that do work have the same number of cookies (well to be precise 1 more as they are sending the one that is dropped from the broken request).

I can make the cookie names and values a little shorter, but I'd prefer first to understand what it is that is wrong before making uninformed changes.

Comment: According to your last sentence, do you mean that you've tried to make the cookie names shorter and succeed? But I think the length maybe not the reason. I've found an article about cookie limits and your cookies' size seem not exceed limit.https://textslashplain.com/2018/10/09/cookie-limits/.I'd like to ask that Could you provide your testing demo so that it could be easier to help you?

Comment: I have not yet tried making cookie names shorter - I'm just saying that I can (we have full control of the app so this is an option for us). I likewise agree that cookie name length didn't seem like the best candidate so haven't attempted that yet. I did experiment with halving the length of the cookie value from 64 chars to 32. It did not help, the issue still occurs. I'll try to provide more detail in near future.